# How to run a job every 6 hours in gitlab-ci.yml (or run all jobs)

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, jobs, continuous-deployment, runner

I know this seems to be a copy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627464/gitlab-ci-setup-every-day-builds), but the answer for that question doesn't solves my purpose.

I don't want to run a curl command in my system. Instead I need Gitlab to take care of running the job every 6 hours. I came across documentation about Pipeline schedules, but it is not available right now in current version.

[image]

Comment: It should be avaiable as it is included from 9.1 and the current version is 10.4.0, or do you mean your currently installed version is older than 9.1. [Pipeline Schedule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html)

Comment: @secustor I'm using the GItlab.com web version. As per documentation it should be available in Pipelines -> Schedules menu. But i'm not able to see schedules menu or button anywhere in pipelines page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using the old navigation interface which should be, as I know, already deprecated.

To migrate to the new one the gitlab blog has this to say.

> To turn the new navigation on, click your user profile dropdown and select "Turn on new navigation" or visit your user preferences.

If you have done this you will find the schedules under CI/CD on your left hand side.
[image]

Comment: Yes, right and thanks. To add to it, I am using enterprise edition of gitlab and to check the version of gitlab we need to navigate to "Your Enterprise gitlab url/help".

Comment: If you have access to the admin panel, you will also find the Gitlab version under components on the upper right hand side.